# Where to get ajaxmin.exe?

Tags: microsoft-ajax-minifier, ajaxmin

I want to minify my js and css through command prompt using ajaxmin. Can someone provide the link for this.  This https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ajaxmin does not have the exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is what I did:

1. npm install uglify-es -g
2. uglifyjs File.js --mangle --compress --verbose --warn --timings --output minfiedFile.min.js

for more https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone needs it, you can download the installer or portable [from here](https://github.com/anag0/MicrosoftAjaxMinInstaller).

Answer (score 3):

The source code and binary releases are now available on [Microsoft's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/ajaxmin/).

Microsoft Ajax Minifier v5.14 is available to download from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ajaxmin/releases/tag/v5.14

The zip archive release contains a "AjaxMinSetup.msi" file, which will install the "AjaxMin.exe" in your Program Files folder.